# Airflow connection __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'api_version'

Tags: airflow

I am trying to connect the postgres hosted on GCP cloudsql to apache airflow running on local machine via docker compose.
I am getting the following error on the console. How may I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Did the error message result from using the "Test" button?

Comment: Did you ever manage to figure this out? I'm having the same issue

Comment: Following this, i'm having the same issue.

Comment: how did you managed to fix this??